# How can I avoid incorrect variable?

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to set a filename using a variable, but if I use an underscore in the filename after a variable name, it uses the `_` as part of the variable name:

eg:

```
set var sometext
set filename "$var_a.txt"
```

The problem is, it now cannot the variable called `var_a`. Is there a way I can force the substitution ending at the _, without using the append command (I want to keep it neat on a single line if possible). I cannot use concat as it puts a space between the two values.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way is to delimit the variable name:

```
set filename "${var}_a.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, a complex set of substitutions is best handled with `format`:

```
set var sometext
set filename [format "%s_a.txt" $var]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, an out-place substitution/ assembly is convenient and robust:

```
append filename $var "_a.text"
```

or, starting with Tcl 8.6 and w/o receiving variable

```
string cat $var "_a.text"
```